# Is it possible to have Ant print out the classpath for a particular target? If so, how?

Tags: java, ant, classpath, target

I'm trying to get a target to build that has quite a long list of `<pathelement location="${xxx}"/>` and `<path refid="foo.class.path"/>` elements in its `<path id="bar.class.path">` element (in the build.xml file).  I keep getting "package com.somecompany.somepackage does not exist" errors, and I'm having a hard time chasing down these packages and making sure I've synced them from our repository.

I'm new to this team so I'm unfamiliar with the build, but I would prefer to figure this out myself if possible (so I don't bother the other very busy team members).  I have very limited experience with Ant.

I think it would save me quite a bit of time if I could have Ant print out the classpath for the target I'm trying to build.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Use the `pathconvert` task to convert a path to a property

```
<path id="classpath">
....
</path>

<pathconvert property="classpathProp" refid="classpath"/>

<echo>Classpath is ${classpathProp}</echo>
```

[Docs for pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html).

Answer (score 74):

This is even easier with versions of Ant > 1.6

```
<echo>${toString:classpath}</echo>
```

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#pathshortcut for more information