# how do I know what classpath ant uses

Tags: java, ant, build

Is there a way I can "echo" the classpath that ant uses (while it is building the classes,jars, etc as per the build.xml) ? I am not changing the classpath from the build.xml file. So I guess, ant should use system's(I am on a Linux system) CLASSPATH variable.

Answer (score 3):

The `environment` attribute of the `<property>` tag reads the system environment variables and stores them in properties, (in the example below) prefixed with `env`.

Then, in order to print them, you can use `<echo>`

```
<property environment="env"/>
<echo message="CLASSPATH: ${env.CLASSPATH}"/>
```

More info:

- [Ant's 'Property' task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html)
- [How to print the classpath in a particular Ant task ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430445/is-it-possible-to-have-ant-print-out-the-classpath-for-a-particular-target-if-s)

Comment: Doesn't ANT build its own classpath for compilation though? I wouldn't expect a CLASSPATH environmental variable to have any influence on it, otherwise you'd get different results on different machines.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But what I'm pointing in my example is that you can access the values of the system variables (and print them). And I believe that the thing the OP asks.

Comment: Hmmm I see. Actually I want to "echo" the classpath that Ant uses while it is compiling (if I run it on the command line, like : **$ ant** ). Is there a way to get that ?

Comment: Yes, see my updated answer (the second link)